# Making graphs from database with Time/Date field

Tags: database, libreoffice

I've been trying to make a diagram from a LibreOffice (version 4.2.8.2) Base database with a date/time field, by copying the table in Calc. But the graph completely ignores the time part.

To explain what I mean, I've made a simple example database with one table. Here's the table definition:

[image: Table definition]

And here's the table content, as defined in Base:

[image: Table content]

I've then copy/pasted the table into a new Calc document, and generated a graph from the data. The result looks like this:

[image: Resulting diagram]

As you can see, in the copied data, both date and time are still there, but in the diagram, the time is set to 0:00 for all data points, making the diagram wrong.

So what do I have to do to get a correct diagram from my database?

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this question please add a comment what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check the chart type - is hat to be `XY (Scatter)`. Second, check the content type of the `Zeit` column. Is it plain text, or are the values recognized as date/time values by LO? To check this, select one of those cells, right-click and select `Format Cells...` - on the `Numbers` tab, LO should have selected a date/time format. Now, it should work:

[image]

See also [this Q/A on creating charts in LO Calc with date (/time) values](https://superuser.com/a/437885/84724).

Comment: Thank you. It was the XY (Scatter) option that I got wrong; I had selected "Line diagram" (or however it is called in the English interface; "Liniendiagramm" in German, located directly above the XY) I now get the correct graph.